# What is the easiest way to send and receive data between a .net windows service and an application

Tags: windows, vb.net, service

I have a software that uses a service to encrypt files. The GUI serializes a hashtable containing the file paths, then uses the `ExecuteCommand` method to notify the service. The service deserializes the hashtable and processes the files.

What I need for the service to do is somehow tell the GUI that it's done processing so the GUI can display some form of notification. What would be the best way for the service to send the data to the GUI? Also if anyone has an alternative to my current method of sending file paths to a service, I am open to suggestions.

EDIT:
This is what I am doing now:

```
Dim sk = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\AesESvc")
Dim scAES As New ServiceProcess.ServiceController("AesESvc")

sk.SetValue("Processing", 1, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)

scAES.ExecuteCommand(132)


Do While (sk.GetValue("Processing") = 1)
    sblProcess.Text = "Processing"
Loop

Dim total As Int32 = lvwLoad.Items.Count - sk.GetValue("ErrorsInLastProcess")

If total > 1 Then
    sblProcess.Text = (total & " items successfully processed." & vbCrLf & sk.GetValue("ErrorsInLastProcess") & " error(s)")
ElseIf total = 1 Then
    sblProcess.Text = (total & " item successfully processed." & vbCrLf & sk.GetValue("ErrorsInLastProcess") & " error(s)")
ElseIf total < 1 Then
    sblProcess.Text = ("None of the items could be processed." & vbCrLf & sk.GetValue("ErrorsInLastProcess") & " error(s)")
End If
```

The service changes the `Processing` registry value to 0 when it is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named pipes should work well. Here's some information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx

Comment: It's a little messy, but I looked into this in .net 2005 and it was the easiest then. I don't think there's anything new in 2008, but I don't know about the newer Visual Studios.

Comment: Would this be the easiest way? All I need is for the service to send some kind of trigger to the GUI so the GUI can display the message. Using pipes seems like way too much extra code just to send one message to the program.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If I ever have an inter-process communication project big enough to warrant pipes, I'll definitely keep this in mind. :)

Comment: I used it just to pass a filename. If you find something simpler, please post a comment!

Comment: I use binary serialization because my hashtable contains the filename as the key and the type of process (encrypt or decrypt) as the value. Right now I have a `Do While...Loop` structure that checks a value in the registry. When the service changes the value, the GUI displays the notification.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, that won't work for my application. (If you haven't already, it might be a good idea to put a thread.sleep in the loop to prevent a CPU spike.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Also, instead of named pipes (which seem to be the typical response to IPC-related questions), try **anonymous** pipes, which are useful for IPC that is not over a network.